# magento 2: How add time to datepicker in backend

Tags: magento2, module, date, datepicker, time

I'am using magento 2.0.5 and I want to add date field with time which saves date as well as time in database for entity.

I had tried this code to add new field in my module.

```
$fieldset->addField('enddate', 'date', array(
        'name' => 'enddate',
        'label' => __('End date'),
        'title' => __('End date'),
        'format' => 'yy-mm-dd H:i:s',
        'input_format' => 'yy-mm-dd H:i:s',
        'required' => true,
            )
    );
```

but this gives me only date to select not time

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have the declaration of the field similar to the following;

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'date_to',
    'date',
    [
        'name' => 'date_to',
        'label' => __('Start Time'),
        'title' => __('Start Time'),
        'date_format' => $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT),
        'time_format' => $this->_localeDate->getTimeFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT),
        'class' => 'validate-date'
    ]
);
```

The important bits are the *date_format* and *time_format* keys.

Comment: Thank's Smartie, your answer helped me.
I looked in the documentation section that talks about programming forms part of the administration but I have not found anything, if you have links, thank you.

Comment: @smartie,I want to display only time.Please suggest me.